# Connect to SQL server using Pyodbc with out password string and a certificate

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I am able to connect to the SQL server using the 'TrustedConnection = Yes' in the Pyodbc.connect()
But I dont want to use neither the windows credentials nor provide password literal string in the connection()

I am thinking whether i can connect to the sql server using only certificate with out the concept of password in the connection string

At present i am using

```
        pyodbc.connect(
            'DRIVER={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};'
            'SERVER= ' + serverName + ';'
            'DATABASE=' + dbName + ';'
            'Trusted_Connection=yes;')
```

I want to use certificate and not use password in connection string

```
cnx = pyodbc.connect(user="{username@servername}", 
                             ❌password="{password}"❌,  # thinking if we can remove this
                             host="{server_name}",
                             database="{database_name}", 
                            ssl_ca="/home/sachin//root.crt",
                             ssl_verify_cert=True)
```

Comment: *"But I dont want to use neither the windows credentials nor provide password literal string in the connection"* SQL Server only supports 2 authentication methods, Trusted Connections or SQL Authentication. If you don't want to use either of those connection methods, then you can't use SQL Server.

Comment: Also, your code has `cnx = mysql.connector.connect`. If you're using SQL Server, *why* are you using a MySQL object?

Comment: Hi Larnu,  i want to use sql authentication,  no issues with the userName, but instead of password i want to use a ssL certificate for authentication
Is that possible

Comment: SQL Authentication uses a Password, not a certificate.

Answer (score 1):

To quote from the documentation [Authentication in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/authentication-in-sql-server):

> ## Authentication in SQL Server
>
> SQL Server supports two authentication modes, Windows authentication mode and mixed mode.
>
> - Windows authentication is the default, and is often referred to as integrated security because this SQL Server security model is tightly integrated with Windows. Specific Windows user and group accounts are trusted to log in to SQL Server. Windows users who have already been authenticated do not have to present additional credentials.
> - Mixed mode supports authentication both by Windows and by SQL Server. User name and password pairs are maintained within SQL Server.

Those are you're only 2 options. If you then read further on:

> ### Mixed Mode Authentication
>
> If you must use mixed mode authentication, you must create SQL Server logins, which are stored in SQL Server. You then have to supply the SQL Server user name and password at run time.

Note that, again, it explicitly states **password**, nothing else. You can't use something else instead of a password for the connection string. You either need to use a trusted connection, and then the authentication is handled via the domain, or you use SQL Authentication and use a Username and Password.

If you don't want to use these Authentication Methods, then SQL Server is not the right RDBMS choice for you, and you would need to try and find an alternative RDBMS that supports a authentication method you want to use.